# How to install a 'patch' program?

Tags: software-sources, patch

I am unable to install patch program. It is showing: `unable to locate packages`.

Also the folder etc/apt/sources.list is showing main restricted

How to overcome this?

Comment: do you mean you need to install a .patch file for a programme?

Comment: Do you mean [patch](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/patch) ? did you try `sudo apt-get install patch`?

Comment: yeah! i have tried that one already..

Answer (score 7):

Try to install it after an update:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install patch
```